# linear programming slack output more than input

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

VERSIONS:

- SciPy: 0.16

### PROBLEM

I'm trying optimize the function of benefits (code below), but **slack** output doesn't apear correct (red circle) with the result that would be.

The last two results are similar, but one (120) is lost. I don't know why?

```
In [3]:
A = np.array([[1,0],[0,1],[1,2]])

In [4]:
# dispo
b = [60, 50, 120]
bounds = ([1,None],[1,None])
In [5]:

c = np.array([80, 120])
In [10]:
sol = linprog(-c, A, b, bounds=bounds)
In [17]:

sol
Out[17]:
  status: 0
   slack: array([  0.,  20.,   0.,  59.,  29.])
     nit: 5
 success: True
     fun: -8400.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
       x: array([ 60.,  30.])
```

For better context [link to gist](https://gist.github.com/mmngreco/6add50703952fd59d11b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong place in your table. linprog computes `sol.x` as the values on the "Producción" row. It does not return the values in the column you circled, but you can easily compute them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. May be I'm not explain rightly. Into the output of the `scipy.linprog` I have the solution of the system, but I think that the named 'slack' in it, is or would be the circled un red.

Comment: The meaning of the `slack` returned is defined in the documentation of linprog, and it is not what the columns you have circled are. I'm not sure why you expect them to be the same, those aren't usually called slack variables in linear programming (they're related but not the same)?